# Localized shortcuts for official US, not working ones

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016, localization

Apparently Microsoft maintains only one list of Excel keyboard shortcuts for Windows: [Keyboard shortcuts in Excel for Windows](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Excel-for-Windows-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f).

But in *localized* versions of Excel with *various* keyboard layouts *not all of these shortcuts work*.

I know 3 listed Microsoft's shortcuts that *do nothing* in my version, and their *functional* substitutions:

- Switch between displaying cell values or formulas in the worksheet:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (official) does nothing, but
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> works for it.
- Enter the current date:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> (official) does nothing, but
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> works for it.
- Copy a formula from the cell above the active cell into the cell or the Formula Bar:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> (official) does nothing, but
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> works for it.

**So my first question is:**

- *Did national teams for localization of Excel invent their own shortcuts, suppressing those in the Microsoft list?*

**My second question — or request — is:**

- *If you know another alternative shortcuts, please share them here.*

There is no need to answer both my questions at the same time — I will welcome answers to only one of them, too.

**Edit:**

My question is not about particular localization / keyboard layout. My intent is to help people from different parts of the world.

[Seth](https://superuser.com/users/619267/seth) gave me notice about localized Microsoft pages of this theme, but it seems that they contain only the translation of the original text, including the translation of the note

> The shortcuts in this topic refer to the US keyboard layout. Keys for other layouts might not correspond exactly to the keys on a US keyboard.

Then follow the same keyboard shortcuts as in the original page. Not very useful.

Comment: "There is no need to answer both my questions at the same time - I will welcome answers to only one of them, too." - Then only ask one of your questions.   What localization are you using?  Edit your question.  I have my reasons for asking about what localization your using.  So please provide that information.

Comment: You have to take into consideration your own keyboard layout. It's likely that, that help is based on the US layout. So with your example of `Ctrl+grave accent (\`)` I'd have to press `Ctrl+Shift+grave accent(\`)` to make it work with my layout. Looking at the localized article I'm also actually seeing that localized shortcut.

Comment: "The shortcuts in this topic refer to the US keyboard layout. Keys for other layouts might not correspond exactly to the keys on a US keyboard." which means "Did national teams for localization of Excel invent their own shortcuts, suppressing those in the Microsoft list?" - is very unlikely that is case and the use of `,` instead of `'` is likely based only on your keyboard layout.  I would have to know which keyboard layout to explain the differences.

Comment: @Seth - Many shortcuts work as you indicated, but some of them not - as in my second example. No consideration about current keyboard layout helps, even after switching to US keyboard layout. - Microsoft has localized articles about it? I'm not able to find it.

Comment: Change the language in the URL. So e.g. replace `en-gb` with `de-de` or whatever would be suitable for your region.

Comment: @Seth - Nice tip, but in the top of the localized page is a (translated) note: "The shortcuts in this topic refer to the US keyboard layout. Keys for other layouts might not correspond exactly to the keys on a US keyboard." And then follows the translation of the original English text only. Very useful ... :-).  Nevertheless thank you for it, I edited my question to include this information.