# Editing mode and using "switch to formulas" keyboard shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

While in the *editing mode*, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>  (or the appropriate [localized keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/q/1289225/705820), as I do myself),
then the actual *cell's border* disappears and so do the *narrow lines* under (right of) highlighted column letter (row number).

You may see it after entering `1` and `4`:

[image]

Is it only a visual effect, or the indicator of some different behavior?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (single left quotation mark) is defined to ‘*Toggle between showing formula and formula result*’.

When you press it, you see the ‘result’ of the ‘formula’ (`14` in your example), in normal Excel display mode, so the box disappears.
If you press it again, it toggles back to the formula entering mode (with the box arounf the current cell).

The toggle is more useful for real formulas, for entered text/numbers, it has little practical use (and the observed strange effect).

Comment: *"If you press it again, it toggles back to the formula entering mode (with the box arounf the current cell)"* - no, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: *"The toggle is more useful for real formulas"* - why? I don't see any other effect beside those described in my question.

Comment: In any case, thank you for your effort. It would be nice from you to add some link(s) to the sources supported your answer.